# Why ToDate does not work with string format

Tags: apache-pig

Assume that I have a string column named DAT_015_X in that format 'yyyyMMdd'.

I want to create a filter by the date '20190101'.

I just load my data :

```
CRE_22002 = LOAD '$input' USING  PigStorage(';') AS (GM_COMPTEUR:chararray,CIA_CD_CRV_CIA:chararray,CIA_DA_EM_CRV:chararray,CIA_CD_CTRL_BLCE:chararray,CIA_IDC_EXTR_RDJ:chararray,CIA_VLR_IDT_CRV_LOQ:chararray,CIA_VLR_REF_CRV:chararray,CIA_NO_SEQ_CRV:chararray,CIA_VLR_LG_ZON_RTG:chararray,CIA_HEU_CIA:chararray,CIA_TM_STP_CRE:chararray,CIA_CD_SI:chararray,CIA_VLR_1:chararray,CIA_DA_ARR_FIC:chararray,CIA_TY_ENR:chararray,CIA_CD_BTE:chararray,CIA_CD_PER:chararray,CIA_CD_EFS:chararray,CIA_CD_ETA_VAL_CRV:chararray,CIA_CD_EVE_CPR:chararray,CIA_CD_APLI_TDU:chararray,CIA_CD_STE_RTG:chararray,CIA_DA_TT_RTG:chararray,CIA_NO_ENR_RTG:chararray,CIA_DA_VAL_EVE:chararray,PSE_001:chararray,STR_002:chararray,STR_003:chararray,CPR_006_VLR:chararray,CPR_006_DCM:chararray,CPR_006_CD_DVS:chararray,CPR_008_VLR:chararray,CPR_008_DCM:chararray,CPR_008_CD_DVS:chararray,CPR_009_VLR:chararray,CPR_009_DCM:chararray,CPR_009_CD_DVS:chararray,CPR_059_VLR:chararray,CPR_059_DCM:chararray,CPR_059_CD_DVS:chararray,CPR_060_VLR:chararray,CPR_060_DCM:chararray,CPR_060_CD_DVS:chararray,RUB_205:chararray,RUB_216:int,DAT_015_X:chararray,NB_005_VLR:chararray,NB_005_DCM:chararray,NB_007_VLR:chararray,NB_007_DCM:chararray,NB_012_VLR:chararray,NB_012_DCM:chararray,EUR_061_VLR:chararray,EUR_061_DCM:chararray,EUR_061_CD_DVS:chararray,EUR_062_VLR:chararray,EUR_062_DCM:chararray,EUR_062_CD_DVS:chararray);
```

I dumped it and data exist and there was no problem. No space or any problem.

To get the filter I write :

```
CRE_22002_DATA_FILTER = FILTER CRE_22002  BY (ToDate($45,'yyyyMMdd')> ToDate('20190101','yyyyMMdd'));
```

I get this error :

> Could not infer the matching function for
>   org.apache.pig.builtin.ToDate as multiple or none of them fit. Please
>   use an explicit cast.

**EDIT**
@VK_217 as say, I used $45 instead $44 beacuse it's the right position.

```
(DAT_015_X)
(99991231)
(20200605)
(20190605)
(20200605)
(20200305)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(20200110)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(20190501)
(99991231)
(20190905)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(20190605)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(20190905)
(99991231)
(20190915)
(20190805)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(99991231)
(20200110)
(99991231)
(20190705)
```

But there is always an error :

> []]: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "DAT_015_X"

```
Failed Jobs:
JobId   Alias   Feature Message Outputs
job_1549794175705_3562351       CRE_22002,CRE_22002_DATA_FILTER,LIMITED_DATA            Message: Job failed!

Input(s):
Failed to read data from "/hdfs/data/adhoc/PR/02/RDO0/BB0/MGM22002-2019-09-04.csv"

Output(s):
```

How do you explain that please ?

Comment: Can you post what you get from the $44 field when you dump it. Run this below pig script and post your result.

Comment: CRE_DATE = FOREACH CRE_22002 GENERATE $44 as my_date;
DUMP CRE_DATE; or CRE_DATE = FOREACH CRE_22002 GENERATE DAT_015_X as my_date;
DUMP CRE_DATE;

Comment: @VK_217, ok just a minut

Comment: @VK_217, just look to the edited question

Comment: Most likely the problem is date range 99991231. Replace it with unix epoch 20380119 and give it a shot.So after load CRE_DATE = FOREACH CRE_22002 GENERATE REPLACE(DAT_015_X,'99991231','20380119') as my_date;CRE_22002_DATA_FILTER = FILTER CRE_DATE  BY (ToDate(my_date,'yyyyMMdd') > ToDate('20190101','yyyyMMdd'));

Comment: By the way, why do you need this date 99991231? Your filter would include this.

Comment: @VK_217, I asked the same question to my boss and he says this is normal

Comment: did the replace work?

Comment: @VK_217, no at all

Comment: @VK_217, the problem is why it doesn't accept the format of the `DAT_015_X` as chararray at all !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199262/discussion-between-vk-217-and-sa2018).